# Social Login using oauthconnector fails to display on login form

Tags: users, commerce

I've followed www.drupalcommerce.org/blog/4571/kickstart-tip-1-social-logins-made-simple
to a T, including changing permissions.

I must be missing something silly, as the login options are still not showing up on the login form.

What am I missing?

Comment: going to need more information to help with this -- can you check the status report and errors log to see if there is anything being reported there? Is there a URL you can make available where we can see what is being output? Can you check the source code of your user login form to see if it is being added to the page but not displaying due to CSS issues, etc.? Do you have any other user login form related modules enabled or custom templating?

Comment: I solve the same issue by Checking in permission for anonymous user.